# Bot Framework Forward Type Arguments Error

Tags: c#, botframework

I am getting this following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQweh.png)
when trying to use the MS Bot Framework Example to call a different dialog. This is my code:

```html
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace ReadMeBot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            if (activity != null && activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("what is"))
            {
                await
                    context.Forward(new InternetSearchDialog(), this.ResumeAfterInternetSearchDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
            }

            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters. Thank you!");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterInternetSearchDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? I googled around and nobody seems to have this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are forwarding to another dialog, you don't need to wait in this dialog.  You'll want to call context.Wait in the resume though.

Things should work as expected if you change your code to something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        if (activity != null && activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("what is"))
        {
            await
                context.Forward(new InternetSearchDialog(), this.ResumeAfterInternetSearchDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters. Thank you!");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }       
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterInternetSearchDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your comment. The code above did not solve the issue, however.

Comment: Please post your InternetSearchDialog in your question.